# How to find place in the code where Doctrine's exceptions was raised?

Tags: php, debugging, exception, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I had MappingException somewhere in my code. Please help me how to find place in a code where that exception is raising?

```
[29-Mar-2019 22:30:26 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class 'Client' does not exist in /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(24): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('Client')
#1 /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(251): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses('Client')
#2 /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(284): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses('Client')
#3 /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doc in /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 93
```

If i will do something like that will it help or i'll get the same stack trace which i have now?

```
try {
    // application init
    $app->init();
} catch (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException $e) {
    error_log("MappingException: " . $e->getTraceAsString());
    throw $e;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Problem wasn't related to Doctrine exactly but to length of stack trace which too big and doesn't fit to 1024 bytes by (default php's setting). So, just need to increase max length of stack trace which can be done by follow command:

```
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0); // 0 - infinity length allow
```

Comment: I haven't worked with doctrine. But looks like a failed dependency injection. Does any of your classes await a dependency of a Client class?

Comment: Yes, looks like dependency injection issue, i've checked all my entities, repositories and everything else and didn't find anything. I think that modern ORM tool should provide detailed bug report which include place in the code where exception raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't related to Doctrine exactly but to length of stack trace which too big and doesn't fit to 1024 bytes by (default php's setting). So, just need to increase max length of stack trace which can be done by follow command:

```
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0); // 0 - infinity length allow
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception was thrown at:

> file:
>   /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php
>
> line: 93

If you want to see what happened before (a cause) you can check trace of your code. I don't see whole your code but:

If you have **Uncaught** exception even you wrapped your code with try catch block there are only two main ways here:

**1. You don't catch the exception. Probably because of not escaping the exception you want to catch or the exception is different than you try to catch. Or you re-throw it (probably your case)**

try this way of catching with `\Exception`

```
try {
    // application init
    $app->init();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log("MappingException: " . $e->getTraceAsString());
    //no throw
}
```

if this works then you may change your code to have such way of catching exceptions

```
try {
    // application init
    $app->init();

//note backslash
} catch (\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException $e) {
    error_log("MappingException: " . $e->getTraceAsString());
    //no throw

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log("GeneralExcpeption: " . $e->getTraceAsString());
    //no throw
}
```

You always catch exceptions starting from most specific (Doctrine in your case) to less specific (\Exception)

Probably it will be much easier to work with [getTrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php) than with getTraceAsString() to see the execution order that led to exception.
but do yourself a favor and limit the amount of entries you display ie this way:

```
try {
    // application init
    $app->init();

//note backslash
} catch (\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException $e) {

    var_export(array_slice($e->getTrace(), 0, 5));
    //no throw

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    var_export(array_slice($e->getTrace(), 0, 5));
    //no throw
}
```

and go backwards to the place where you used `Client` if number 5 is not enough then increase it to 10, 15 etc to be able to go backwards where the execution was before an exception happened. Each entry has file and line number so you'll be able to recreate what happend.

Look at your code where you have your `Client` and check that you used proper use of that Client in the namespace you are. If there is a `namespace` keyword at the top of the php file where you use `Client` you need to be sure the `Client` is part of that `namespace` or use `\Client` to escape the namespace and treat the name `Client` as if there was no namespace.

**2. The exception is thrown outside of your try catch block (probably not)**

You can try to catch exceptions that are outside your try/catch block by registering your own function with handler. The tricky part is that this must be done before an exception is thrown so perfectly at the first line of the php code. Note this might be different line than the first line you wrote for example this can be application bootstrap.php.
you may check what is your app first line by running app with Xdebug, into debug mode.

here's example of putting exeption handler:

```
<?php
function exception_handler($e) {
  echo "MyUncaughtException: " , $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimmix! From you long comment $e->getTrace() helped me to analyse stack trace and found solution.

Comment: > file: /var/www/virtual/account/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php

line: 93

Comment: @AndreyLebedev You are welcome, if the answer satisfied you please consider marking it as accepted so your question appears to others as already answered.